# Token mismatch with ajax post request to a subdomain

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

I am developing a web app using the Laravel framework.

When I send an ajax request from app.com to api.app.com passing the csrf token generated at app.com, I always get the TokenMismatchException.

The problem is that ajax request to api.app.com is creating a new session there.
I am using a single laravel installation for app.com and api.app.com.

Subdomain routes:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => 'api.app.com'), function()
{
    Route::controller('user', 'MyApp\API\UserController');
});
```

CSRF Filter is applied only to POST request:

```
Route::when('*', 'csrf', ['post']);
```

CSRF Filter:

```
Route::filter('csrf', function()
{
    $token = Input::get('_token');

    if (Session::token() != $token)
    {
        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
    }
});
```

My ajax request looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    'url': '//api.app.com/user/hello',
    'data': {
        fields:'',
        '_token': 'output of csrf_token() from app.com'
    },
    'dataType': 'json',
    'type': 'POST'
}).done(done).fail(fail).always(always);
```

Everything works fine if I don't use a subdomain for my api.
I am using memcached as my session storage.

**EDIT:**
My session domain is set to .app.com.

```
'domain' => '.app.com',
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by sending the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` header and changing my ajax request function to this:

```
$.ajax({
    'url': '//api.app.com/user/hello',
    'data': {
        fields:'',
        '_token': 'output of csrf_token() from app.com'
    },
    'dataType': 'json',
    'type': 'POST',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    }
}).done(done).fail(fail).always(always);
```